# Trocar imagem clicando nela (JS, jQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou querendo clicar numa imagem, e quando eu clico nela, vai puxar um api e quero que a imagem mude para outra, só que eu não to conseguindo mudar a imagem.

Obs.: o API ta funcionando, só preciso saber como mudar de foto quando eu clico nela.

Comment: Oi Nazare, podes mostrar o código que tens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo a URL da nova imagem, você só precisa selecionar o elemento `<img>` a ser trocado e mudar o atributo `src` dele. No exemplo abaixo escolhi duas URLs e usei JavaScript puro para rotacionar entre elas a cada clique no link ou na imagem usando `addEventListener`:

```js
function mudaImagem () {
  var imgA = 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/51/4d/2e514d03b0414f8b7c5adefa5cbccba4--wink-wink-adorable-animals.jpg';
  var imgB = 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ae/d7/bc/aed7bcbe347a262f89cc3867cdce54c2--cutest-kittens-ever-cute-baby-animals.jpg';
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  img.src = (img.src == imgA ? imgB : imgA);
}

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', mudaImagem, true);
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', mudaImagem, true);
```

```css
img {
  border: 10px solid white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Mudar imagem</a>
<br>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/51/4d/2e514d03b0414f8b7c5adefa5cbccba4--wink-wink-adorable-animals.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a Resposta acima, o ideal seria ao invés de usar document.querySelector usar document.getElementById como seletor pois com certeza existem mais de 1 imagem e mais de 1 link na sua aplicação, pois o getElementById seleciona através de uma id que deve ser unica assim sendo possivel garantir o funcionamento.

Segue o Exemplo do nunks.lol alterado da forma como expliquei.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
  function mudaImagem () {
    var imgA = 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/51/4d/2e514d03b0414f8b7c5adefa5cbccba4--wink-wink-adorable-animals.jpg';
    var imgB = 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ae/d7/bc/aed7bcbe347a262f89cc3867cdce54c2--cutest-kittens-ever-cute-baby-animals.jpg';
    var img = document.getElementById('clickImagem');
    img.src = (img.src == imgA ? imgB : imgA);
  }

  document.getElementById('clickLink').addEventListener('click', mudaImagem, true);
  document.getElementById('clickImagem').addEventListener('click', mudaImagem, true);
</script>
```

CSS

```
img {
  border: 10px solid white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a id="clickLink" href="#">Mudar imagem</a>
<br>
<img id="clickImagem" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/51/4d/2e514d03b0414f8b7c5adefa5cbccba4--wink-wink-adorable-animals.jpg">
```

Comment: Douglas, e se quando eu clicasse em outro link pretendendo que o anterior voltasse à imagem normal que estava antes de ser clicada, como seria???